# Find an equation of the sphere with center $(3,−2,1)$ and that goes through the point $(4,2,5)$

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus

> Find an equation of the sphere with center $(3,−2,1)$ and that goes through the point $(4,2,5)$

I did the following:

$r^2=(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2+(z-l)^2$

Since that is the equation of a sphere I simply plugged in the center and the points supplied to get:

$r^2=(4-3)^2+(2+2)^2+(5-1)^2 \Rightarrow r=\sqrt{33}$

This solution just provides the radius, so how do I represent this as an equation?

Comment: If you find the radius between the two points, then all you need to do is set up the equation using the center point of the sphere equaling the radius squared.

Comment: Plug in values of $r, h, k, l$ in the formula that you wrote. That is your equation.

Comment: Ahhh, much easier than I was making it out to be!  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @inquisitor You're welcome! The answer I put is in Cartesian coordinates, will that suffice or were you looking for a spherical polar coordinate form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the center of the sphere has coordinates $(h,k,l)$ and radius $r$ the equation is $$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2+(z-l)^2=r^2$$Plugging in the value known for $r$ (as you stated in the question) and the coordinates of the center, the equation becomes $$(x-3)^2+(y+2)^2+(z-1)^2=33$$

Answer (score 2):

$$(x-3)^2+(y+2)^2+(z-1)^2=33$$ is the equation of the sphere now that you have the coordinates of the centre and know the radius.